# Getting Slow operation detected: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.DeleteOperation while calling ITopic.publish()

Tags: spring, concurrency, hazelcast

[SpringBoot Application] I am trying to delete a key from Hazelcast Map from an async Method. In the Delete Method of the MapStore class, I am trying to put a key into a topic and calling Publish().However, sometimes I am getting this message 
**Slow operation detected: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.DeleteOperation**. I am adding the stack trace below.

2019-03-27 11:52:08.041 [31m WARN[0;39m [] 24586 --- [trace=,span=] [35m[hz._hzInstance_1_gaian.SlowOperationDetectorThread][0;39m [33mc.h.s.i.o.s.SlowOperationDetector       [0;39m: [localhost]:5701 [gaian] [3.10] Slow operation detected: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.DeleteOperation

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:304)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:160)
com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invokeOnPartition(ClientProxy.java:225)
com.hazelcast.client.proxy.PartitionSpecificClientProxy.invokeOnPartition(PartitionSpecificClientProxy.java:49)
com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientTopicProxy.publish(ClientTopicProxy.java:52)
com.gaian.adwize.cache.mapstore.CampaignMapStore.delete(CampaignMapStore.java:95)
com.gaian.adwize.cache.mapstore.CampaignMapStore.delete(CampaignMapStore.java:36)
com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapStoreWrapper.delete(MapStoreWrapper.java:115)
com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writethrough.WriteThroughStore.remove(WriteThroughStore.java:56)
com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writethrough.WriteThroughStore.remove(WriteThroughStore.java:28)
com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.delete(DefaultRecordStore.java:565)
com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.DeleteOperation.run(DeleteOperation.java:38)
com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:148)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:202)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:191)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:406)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:433)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:581)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:566)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:525)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:215)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:60)
com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:67)
com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:130)
com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:110)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:155)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
```

Any help from the community will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider taking the tour. Users are much more likely to help if you [learn how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) around here. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your specific problem.

Comment: Some general question cleanup

Comment: There is no error. This is a stack trace indicating a location in the code. `sun.misc.Unsafe.park` is just a method in the trace like any other. Nowhere does the stack trace  say that an error happened.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add below line.

2019-03-26 19:40:39.096 [31m WARN[0;39m [] 22868 --- [trace=,span=] [35m[hz._hzInstance_1_gaian.SlowOperationDetectorThread][0;39m [33mc.h.s.i.o.s.SlowOperationDetector       [0;39m: [localhost]:5701 [gaian] [3.10] Slow operation detected: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.DeleteOperation

So, whenever i do a delete operation i am getting this slow thread detected message and the published message is not reaching the listener.

Answer (score 2):

Slow operation is not necessarily an error. The newer versions of Hazelcast can calculate what is a normal response time and detect when something is out of ordinary. It’s usually more of a network latency issue or garbage collection introducing latency.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. This is visible in Hazelcast Version 4.0.x as well.